# Simplificar mouseenter e mouseleave de várias imagens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um menu superior feito por imagens e gostaria de quando passar o mouse todas as outras imagens exceto a selecionada diminuam a opacidade. Só que o meu código fica muito grande, gostaria de poder diminuir para facilitar a leitura e interpretação. São ao total 9 imagens.

HTML:

```
<div class="navHeader">
    <a href="box" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="BOX BANHEIRO" style="margin: 0 !important;" >
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav1.png" alt="Borto Vidros Box Banheiro" id="img" />
    </a>
    <a href="janelas"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="JANELAS">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav2.png" alt="Borto Vidros Janelas" id="img1" />
    </a>
    <a href="portas-externas" title="PORTAS EXTERNAS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav3.png" alt="Borto Vidros Portas Externas" id="img2"/>
    </a>
    <a href="portas-internas" title="PORTAS INTERNAS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav4.png" alt="Borto Vidros Portas Internas" id="img3"/>
    </a>
    <a href="sacadas" title="SACADAS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav5.png" alt="Borto Vidros Sacadas" id="img4"/>
    </a>
    <a href="vidros-especiais" title="VIDROS ESPECIAIS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav6.png" alt="Borto Vidros Vidros Especiais" id="img5"/>
    </a>
    <a href="moveis" title="MÓVEIS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav7.png" alt="Borto Vidros Móveis" id="img6"/>
    </a>
    <a href="muretas" title="MURETAS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav9.png" alt="Borto Vidros Muretas" id="img7"/>
    </a>
    <a href="escadas" title="ESCADAS" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <img src="{$path}/img/nav10.png" alt="Borto Vidros Escadas" id="img8"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var box = ["#img","#img1","#img2","#img3","#img4","#img5","#img6","#img7","#img8"];

$('#box').mouseenter(function(){
    for(var i=1; i<box.length;i++){
    $(box[i]).css({opacity:0.5});
}});
$('#box').mouseleave(function(){
    for(var i=1; i<box.length;i++){
        $(box[i]).css({opacity:1});
}});
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor a pergunta? colocar HTML e explicar o que colocou aqui ajudaria a compreender o que quer.

Comment: Ok e quer que as imagens fiquem com opacity `0.5` quando o mouse estiver em cima delas? Nesse caso basta CSS: `.navHeader img:hover{ opacity: 0.5;}`

Comment: isso, o mouse entra as outras imagens ficam mais transparentes, para fazer com que dê foco na que foi selecionada, quando sair volta o menu ao normal

Comment: Já experimentou só com CSS como escrevi em cima?

Comment: Quando você diz que "o código fica muito grande", você se refere ao HTML? Ou seria uma questão de simplificar o JavaScript? (como você está usando jQuery, tenho sugestões nesse sentido, se for o que você quer)

Comment: O css deixa apenas a selecionada com opacity 0,5, a intenção é as outras ficaram com baixa opacidade quando selecionado a outra

Comment: Isso quero diminuir o javascript.

Comment: Você pode até otimizar o JS por usar mais da jQuery, mas diminuir, eu acho que já está bem enxuto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode fazer isso só com CSS:

```
.navHeader:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.navHeader img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/qcT89/

Se quiser pode ainda adicionar transições para suavisar com `transition: opacity 0.5s;`

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/qcT89/1/

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito prático assim, não tinha pensado nisso

Comment: Percebi uma inconsistência muito, mas muito pequena mesmo, em que quando nenhuma imagem está recebendo o *hover* mas o mouse ainda esteja sobre seu elemento-pai, todas as imagens continuam com opacidade reduzida até que o mouse seja movido para outro elemento. [Uma possível](http://jsfiddle.net/qcT89/2/) gambiarra seria setar um `display: inline;` no elemento-pai, porém as imagens "piscam" ao passar o mouse no espaço vazio entre elas.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto sim, verdade. Mas só para poupar no JS vale a pena ter um wrapper extra para corrigir isso.

Comment: Com certeza. Essa gambiarra do `display`, se aplicada [junto com a transição](http://jsfiddle.net/qcT89/3/), torna esse efeito colateral imperceptível.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto bem visto ++

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) para excluir um único elemento de um seletor (no caso o `this`):

```
$(".navHeader img").hover(function() {
    $(".navHeader img").not(this).css({ opacity:0.5 });
}, function() {
    $(".navHeader img").not(this).css({ opacity:1 });
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5T7Bx/). P.S. [A solução do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27793/215), somente com CSS, é uma opção preferível.

Answer (score 1):

Faça uso do `.children()` para pegar os filhos da classe *.navHeader* e uso do `.not()` para aplicar exceto na que chamou.

```
$('.navHeader').children().hover(
  function() {
    $('.navHeader').children().not(this).css({opacity:0.5});
  }, function() {
    $('.navHeader').children().not(this).css({opacity:1});
  }
);
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/2EE37/**